# Get Managed Identity Application ID from ADF with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, hashicorp

I would like to retrive the Managed Identity Application ID from my adf using the `data sources`. I have tried this

```
provider "azurerm" {
features {}
}

data "azurerm_data_factory" "adf" {
  name                = "adf-dev-gg-we-01"
  resource_group_name = "your_resource_group_name"
}

output "managed_identity_application_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_data_factory.adf.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

but it retrives `Managed Identity Object ID` but I would like to get the  `Managed Identity Application ID`! How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly retrieve the managed identity`client_id` value from a resource. Instead use data source of an [`azuread_service_principal`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/service_principal) to get it as shown below.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
features {}
}
data "azurerm_data_factory" "adf" {
  name                = "newdfj"
  resource_group_name = "Jahnavi"
}
data "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  object_id = data.azurerm_data_factory.adf.identity.0.principal_id
}
output "managed_identity_application_id" {
  value = data.azuread_service_principal.example.client_id
}
```

*Value to be shown:*

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Error: Unsupported attribute`  `This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "client_id".`   I also had tried that and I get this error

Comment: I just have changed the `client_id` with `application_id` and gave me a desired output. I will still dont know why it worked for you not for me but I will accept your answer